# RS232 serial Y splitter to Raspberry Pi (USB) and thermal printer sometimes blocks flow to printer

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, serial-port, splitter, rs232

We are sniffing data from a restaurant point of sale system (RJ45 to DB9) to its thermal printer by using an RS232 splitter and a Raspberry Pi (DB9 to USB on the Pi).

This has worked great 99% of the time, but very rarely the POS sends a normal print command and the printer won't print. Then, if we unplug the USB on the Pi, the printer prints the receipt, as though it was queued up and blocked by the Pi somehow. This makes no sense as to why it could get blocked as I thought the Y cable created 2 separate streams of serial data, mutually exclusive.

Note: This seems to only occur when the Ruby serial port listener script on the Pi is not running, though we normally shut off the script and the printer still prints...

I cannot replicate this on demand, which has made it even more frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to consider..

- Does that splitter duplicate control lines other than Tx, Rx and GND? If so, I would physically disconnect those lines on the Serial-to-USB side. These lines may be used for flow control. Even Tx pin is not needed for Raspberry Pi side so you may disconnect it as well. Just RX-GND seem to be enough for Pi.
- The RS-232 port on POS may not be able to supply enough current for two connected peers as it's not standard. Using well-shielded & shorter cables may help. Actually it seems that you don't need to use that long black cable on POS side for testing.
- Using RS-232 signal indicator (like this: http://cnc-specialty-store.com/rs232-cables/rs-232-mini-tester-with-led-indicators-db-25-male-to-female ) may help to analyse the problem.
- Monitor voltages of Tx/Rx lines using multimeters to find difference between normal conditions and the 'stuck' condition.
- And please don't forget that the USB-Serial converter itself may have issues. I've heard so many strange issues caused by USB converters. So, if possible, try the same test without using USB-serial converters, which probably requires another equipment such as PC.

In addition, using two USB-Serial converters on Raspberry Pi may help to really duplicate data between the printer and POS, like    [Printer] - RS232 - [Raspberry Pi] - RS232 - [POS] . This probably requires a new program on Pi to actually duplicate the serial data but at least it won't break the rule of RS-232 which is not guaranteed to run on 1:n connections. However, this configuration may be also risky as it can introduce timing issue, especially with non-PC equipments. You may try this if there's nothing else left to try.

Comment: +1 for a list of checkpoints that I can go through. Thanks. It will take a while to test of all of these...

Comment: We removed all the pins except RX, GND as suggested in the first bullet, that seemed to fix the issue. Resolved!

Comment: Looking back, we actually removed all pins except Rx and GND on the end of the splitter that connects to the serial -> USB -> Pi. We haven't had issues since then but now I'm baffled why that end of the DB9 splitter still can possibly transmit data to the serial -> USB if it only has an Rx. I'm confused how this can still work. Any insight? (Re-reading the answer it seems we were supposed to remove the Tx etc. pins from the serial -> USB, which makes sense to me.)

Comment: I believe that the splitter is just a physical connector and knows nothing about RS-232 or serial communications at all - it just connects everything, as if you put a jumper on every single line by wiring. And as I said, connecting splitter to an existing RS-232 actually breaks the rule of RS-232 which is designed for 1 to 1 connection. So your configuration is basically not guaranteed to work. What I suggested was, because of that, the way to minimise impacts on the existing RS-232 connection.